# How do I filter an array when the value is true and display only the key?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my array:

```
array: [{
  _id: 5f62b2bc84a1ef1c5c48d1af,
  eeid: '300094E6E2',
  adminOrganization: true,
  adminEmployees: false,
  adminAssets: true,
  adminConsumables: true,
  adminWarehousing: false,
  grantBy: '300094E6E2',
  grantDate: 2020-10-04T11:46:28.548Z,
  __v: 0
}]
```

I want to filter only true values and display only the key: Below is my desired result:

```
resultingArray = ['adminOrganization', 'adminAssets', 'adminConsumables']
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Object.key` to get all keys in object and `filter` field value is true as

```
var filtered = Object.keys(obj[0]).filter(function(key) {
    return obj[0][key] == true;
});
```

```js
obj = [{
  _id: '5f62b2bc84a1ef1c5c48d1af',
  eeid: '300094E6E2',
  adminOrganization: true,
  adminEmployees: false,
  adminAssets: true,
  adminConsumables: true,
  adminWarehousing: false,
  grantBy: '300094E6E2',
  grantDate: '2020-10-04T11:46:28.548Z',
  __v: 0
}]

;

var filtered = Object.keys(obj[0]).filter(function(key) {
    return obj[0][key] == true;
});

console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: I have in the console.log [ '$init' ]. I got the array from mongodb query; const array = await Access.find( { } ); However, if using static array like the example, it worked fine. Is there a workaround?